# What is this index and match VBA code not working?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck with this snippet of code i've looked over and over but I cannot seem to find the problem. Does anyone know why it gives out an error? A post of the error is shown below.

```
For i = 2 To Total_rows_Pick
    For j = 2 To Total_rows_Dash
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Finished").Range("B2:B1048576"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 4), Worksheets("Finished").Range("A2:A1048576"), 0)), 1) <> 1 Then
            If Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 2) = Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 2) And Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 4) = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 1) Then
                Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 3) = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 3) + Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 3)
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

[image]

Edits (after trying the answer):

[image]

Revised Code (Note it errors as line 3):

```
    For i = 2 To Total_rows_Pick
    For j = 2 To Total_rows_Dash
        m = Application.Match(Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 4), Worksheets("Finished").Range("A2:A1048576"), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Finished").Range("B2:B1048576"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 4), Worksheets("Finished").Range("A2:A1048576"), 0)), 1) <> 1 Then
                If Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 2) = Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 2) And Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 4) = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 1) Then
                    Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 3) = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 3) + Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 3)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Does the value of the cell `Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 4)` exist in `Worksheets("Finished").Range("A2:A1048576")`?

Comment: Not necessarily. Which is why I have the IsError function. If it tries to search and the value is not there, then I would want the code to assign the values from the "Pick-ups" worksheet to the "Finished" worksheet. I tried creating a for-next loop to assign values from "Pick-ups" to "Finished" but I had complications as well

Comment: As Tim says in his answer, `WorksheetFunction.Match` will crash if there is no matching value.  So a `WorksheetFunction.IfError` (as per your original code) won't be of any use because it is too late to do anything by that stage.  And an `IsError` on the line after where it crashes (as per your new code) also won't be of any use.  You need to change your code to use `Application.Match` as Tim suggested, so that errors are returned as error values instead of crashing.

Comment: Hi sorry. I forgot I changed it back. Even with 'Application.Match' it has an error saying "Type mismatch"

Comment: (a) Remove the error messages from the question that are no longer relevant to the posted code - they are going to confuse us.  (b) Is the Type Mismatch occurring on the line saying `m = ...`?  And is `m` declared as a `Variant` (i.e. `Dim m`, or `Dim m As Variant`)?

Comment: Yeah the error is at `m=...`  and I declared m as `Dim m as Long` maybe that's the mistake going to try to make it as variant. I removed the other 2 photos as soon as I fixed the `Application.Match` part

Comment: Yes, `m` needs to be a `Variant`.  A `Long` variable cannot hold an error value.

Comment: Thanks that resolves it my mistake to declare it as long

Comment: FWIW - your statement `If Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Finished").Range("B2:B1048576"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 4), Worksheets("Finished").Range("A2:A1048576"), 0)), 1) <> 1 Then` can now be written as `If Worksheets("Finished").Cells(m + 1, "B").Value <> 1 Then`

Comment: Thanks I'm relatively new to VBA and hopefully I get better. I keep rereading code over and over again because the texts are so long and its hard to keep them all logically aligned in my head

Comment: One other tip - your lines saying `m = ... ` and `If Not IsError(m) Then` should really be placed before the `For j` loop starts because they aren't dependent on the value of `j` - so at the moment you are executing that `m=` statement `Total_rows_Dash - 1` times and always getting the same answer until you move to the next value of `i`.  (And, obviously, if you move the `If` prior to the `For`, you need to move the corresponding `End If` after the corresponding `Next`.)

Comment: True I can imagine it wasting processing time due to it repeating for a couple more times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no match then `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` will throw a run-time error like the one you're seeing (and which you can't trap like that using `IfError()`). If you instead use `Application.Match` then it will return an error value which you can test using `IsError()` before using that return value in Index:

```
Dim m

For i = 2 To Total_rows_Pick
    For j = 2 To Total_rows_Dash
        m = Application.Match(Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 4), _
                           Worksheets("Finished").Range("A2:A1048576"), 0)

        If Not IsError(m) Then
              'rest of your code here
        End If

    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: I found my mistake I resolved it with additional info by @YowE3K